# Coefficient matching proof that $e^{\alpha x-\frac{1}{2} \alpha^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}H_n(x)\alpha^n$, where $H_n(x)$ are Hermite poly.?

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Hermite polynomials can be defined as (from wikipedia):

$$
H_n(x)=(-1)^n e^{x^2/2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{-x^2/2}.
$$ 
I am trying to show that: $e^{\alpha x-\frac{1}{2} \alpha^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}H_n(x)\alpha^n$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. $\quad (1)$

My first attempt to do this is to rewrite using an exponential infinite summation trick:

$$
e^{\alpha x - \frac{\alpha^2}{2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\alpha x - \frac{\alpha^2}{2})^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha^n \frac{( x - \frac{\alpha}{2})^n}{n!}
$$

Now, comparing terms, it seems to be obvious from $(1)$ above that $H_n(x) = ( x - \frac{\alpha}{2})^n$. However, nowhere in the formula for Hermite polynomials above, $H_n(x)=(-1)^n e^{x^2/2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{-x^2/2}$, does it contain $\alpha$. My question is, how can I go from $( x - \frac{\alpha}{2})^n$ to $(-1)^n e^{x^2/2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n} e^{-x^2/2}$? Thank you.

Comment: You are making the wrong comparison!

Comment: Can you tell me why? I have a guess why it might be wrong looking again at it, is it because I am assuming that $H_n(x)$ doesn't contain $\alpha$ while $(x-\frac{\alpha}{2})^n$ does contain $\alpha$, so I can't equate the two?

Comment: Hmmm, I think I might see it, am I right to say that if I decomposed the summaton, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(\alpha x - \frac{\alpha^2}{2})^n}{n!}$, then collected terms by power's of $\alpha$, THEN compared, then it would be right? And so the reason I can't do it like I outlined above, is that I haven't fully ordered the coefficients in front of each power of $\alpha$ yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the desired identity, it is enough to show that for each fixed $x$,
$$ H_n(x)=\frac{d^n}{d\alpha^n}e^{\alpha x-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2}\Big|_{\alpha=0}$$

By completing the square, we may write
$$ e^{\alpha x-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2}=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{2}}$$
and hence
$$\frac{d^n}{d\alpha^n}e^{\alpha x-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2}\Big|_{\alpha=0}=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\frac{d^n}{d\alpha^n}e^{-\frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{2}}\Big|_{\alpha=0}=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(-1)^n\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=H_n(x)$$

Comment: thanks, however, I was looking for another way to show this by coefficient matching, as I wrote above, is there a way to reconcile that? thanks!

Comment: It wasn't clear to me how that would work. Just from looking at small values of $n$, it's certainly not true that $H_n(x)=(x-\frac{\alpha}{2})^n$. Maybe you could expand out $(x-\frac{\alpha}{2})^n$ and then interchange the sums.

Comment: Ah, I think I know where I screwed up, you are right that I need to expand it out first, then I would need to recollect terms according to power's of $\alpha$. Thank you for writing this proof out, that is what I'm actually looking for!

Comment: Can you tell me how you got the second to last equality you have? How are you able to pull out the $(-1)^n$ and also change the differentiation with respect to $x$?

Comment: It's just the chain rule: if $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=P_n(x)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$, then $\frac{d^n}{d\alpha^n}e^{-\frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{2}}=(-1)^nP_n(x-\alpha)e^{-\frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{2}}$. Then set $\alpha=0$.